# How to make changes to docker-compose.yml and Drupal 9 project files correctly if containers are already running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

1. I installed **Docker** and **Docker Compose**
2. I downloaded the latest release [Docker-based Drupal stack](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal)
   (*there are php, mariadb, apache images etc.*) and put it in the my project
   folder `/var/www/html/mydrupaldocker`
3. Next, I made the settings in the `.env` and `docker-compose.yml` files and running the containers with the command:
   `docker-compose up -d`
4. After running images from this folder, as well as adding the [unzip drupal 9 folder](https://www.drupal.org/download) to the my project folder, I will start installing drupal 9 in the browser.

And I have questions on two possible situations:

---

**Situation №1:**

I made mistakes in the file `docker-compose.yml` I have the commented code which is responsible for the few images. Accordingly, the containers were not started. And I want to place the project in another place of the computer (not critical, but it is desirable)

I can do:
`docker-compose stop` 
`docker-compose rm`

Fix everything that I need. And run again:

`docker-compose up -d`

Is it right to do so? Or do I need something otherwise?

---

**Situation №2:**

Everything is set up well, running all the necessary containers, installed the Drupal 9 site in the container. And then I created a sub theme, added content, wrote code in php, js, css files, etc.

How do I commit the changes now? What commands do you need to write in the terminal? For example, in technology such as git, this is done with the commands:
`git add.`
`git commit -m "first"`

How is it done in Docker? Perhaps there will be a situation when I need to roll back the container to the version below.

Comment: For "situation no. 2", can you write out, in a text file, _exactly_ which commands you ran to configure things?  If your laptop crashed, how would you recreate this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's go by each case.

##### Situation No.1

Whenever you make changes to `docker-compose.yml`, it's fine to restart the service/images so they reflect the new changes. It could be as minor as a simple port switch from `80` to `8080`. Hence, you could just do `docker-compose stop && docker-compose up -d` and `docker-cli` will restart the containers with the new changes.

You **don't** really need to remove the containers/services unless you have used custom `Dockerfile` and have made changes to it. Although, your below assumption would still give the same result, it's just has an ***extra step of removing the containers without any changes being done to the actual docker images***.

> I can do: `docker-compose stop`  `docker-compose rm`
>
> Fix everything that I need. And run again:
>
> `docker-compose up -d`

##### Situation No.2

In this you would be committing your entire project to `git` along with your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file from your host machine and not the container. There's no rocket science here.

You **won't be committing your code to git via the containers**. The containers are only for deploying and testing your code. You would be committing just the configuration files i.e `Dockerfile` (if custom is used offcourse) and `docker-compose.yml` file along with your source code to git. The result would be that, any developer who is collaborating with you in a team, can just take a pull of the project and run `docker-compose up -d` and the same containers/services running on your machine will be up and running on the host machine of the other dev.

Regarding how to roll back to old version of `docker` services, you can just rollback to a previous commit and the `docker-compose.yml` will be reverted. Then you can just do:

`docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`